# How to enable Cartesian join in Spark 2.0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to cross join 2 dataframe in Spark 2.0 I am encountering below error:

User class threw exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cartesian joins could be prohibitively expensive and are disabled by default. To explicitly enable them, please set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled = true;
```

Please help me where to set this configuration, I am coding in eclipse.

Answer (score 10):

As the error message clearly states you need to set `spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled = true` to your spark configuration

You can set the same something like below:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
```

Then get or create `SparkSession` by passing this `SparkConf`

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
```

Then do your join...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me.