# Cross join runtime error: Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following function which can be compiled.

```
  def compare(dbo: Dataset[Cols], ods: Dataset[Cols]) = {
    val j = dbo.crossJoin(ods)
    // Tried val j = dbo.joinWith(ods, func.expr("true")) too
    j.take(5).foreach(r => println(r)) 
  }
```

But it got a runtime error when submitting to Spark.

```
Join condition is missing or trivial. (if using joinWith stead of crossJoin)
Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts$$anonfun$apply$21.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1067)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts$$anonfun$apply$21.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1064)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts.apply(Optimizer.scala:1064)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts.apply(Optimizer.scala:1049)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
        at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2814)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2342)
        at MappingPoint$.compare(MappingPoint.scala:43)
        at MappingPoint$.main(MappingPoint.scala:33)
        at MappingPoint.main(MappingPoint.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Why don't you use Spark 2.2 where this (and many more things) got improved a lot? Any reason to stick to 2.1.1? At least give the version a try and see if that fixes it. I think 2.2 could (as the code has changed).

Comment: I think I installed 2.1.1 (the newest version at that time?) a couple of months ago and didn't upgrade it.

Comment: There's no installation of Spark but defining it as a library dependency or in `PATH`. Time to upgrade. At least you'll know if we're fighting something that's been already fixed before (and you won't waste your time).

Comment: Tried 2.2.0 with scala 2.11.8 and still get the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution in [How to enable Cartesian join in Spark 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198834/how-to-enable-cartesian-join-in-spark-2-0).

```
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I simplified the `Cols` case class so that I don't have to type so much, but it is otherwise I believe what you are attempting.

I used Spark 2.1.1:

```
case class Cols (
    A: Int,
    B: String
)

val dbo: Dataset[Cols] = spark.createDataset(
    Seq[Cols](
        Cols(1, "One"),
        Cols(2, "Two")
    )
)
val ods: Dataset[Cols] = spark.createDataset(
    Seq[Cols](
        Cols(3, "Three"),
        Cols(4, "Four")
    )
)

val cartesian: Dataset[(Cols,Cols)] = dbo.crossJoin(ods).map {
    case Row(lA: Int, lB: String, rA: Int, rB: String) => (Cols(lA, lB), Cols(rA, rB))
}
val result: Dataset[Int] = cartesian.map {
    case (l: Cols, r: Cols) => 0
}
```

As long as `Cols` has fewer than 11 elements, you should be OK. Otherwise, you might run into issues trying to pattern match on >22 elements after the `crossJoin`.

It looks to me like what you are submitting to Spark may still be using the `joinWith` line, which Spark apparently attempts to detect and prevent cartesian joins on.

Comment: Can I always use `dbo.joinWith(ods, func.lit(true))` to avoid the issue of >22 elements of the pattern match? BTW, `dbo.joinWith(ods, func.lit(true))` already returns the value with the type of `Dataset[(Cols,Cols)]` so there will be no need to do extra mapping (in your code of `cartesian`. But I still got the error. Maybe there are some system settings to allow cross join?